# SVN repository at existing folder on server

Tags: svn, repository, visualsvn-server

I am new to SVN repository thing:

- I have **VisualSVN Server** installed at my computer.
- I have a gift shop website and it's physical path is  **C:\Hosting\Domains\GiftShop**.
- I want to link the repository I created at VisualSVN to the path mentioned above. How should I do it?

Please advice.

Comment: Repositories are created where the server is installed, do mean you want to create a working copy ?

Comment: It's not clear what the task is. Where is the website located? on the VDS or on your local machine? Is it already in SVN repository? Also make sure to read SVNBook in order not to confuse version-control terms such as *working copy* and *repository*: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/

Answer (score 2):

Supposing `C:\Hosting\Domains\GiftShop` is the directory containing the files of your application and you want to have it version controlled.

For that you need to do the following steps

1. Create a directory in your repository for your project
2. Import your project into the the svn repository
3. Turn the directory containing your locally saved files into a [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.initial.html)

Here are the svn commads witch you need to excecute for each step

1. [svn mkdir](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.mkdir.html)

   ```
   svn mkdir --parents <repo-url>/GiftShop -m="create project GiftShop"
   ```
2. [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html)

   ```
   svn import <repo-url>/GiftShop/trunk  -m="initial import GiftShop"
   ```
3. [svn checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html)

   ```
   svn checkout --revision HEAD --depth infinity --force <repo-url>/GiftShop/trunk GiftShop
   ```

If you are wondering why there is a directory `trunk` you may then want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761985/best-practice-for-project-directory-structure-and-source-control) about best practice for project directory structure under subversion.

All these commands need to be run from the parent directory of `GiftShop`, in your case it is `C:\Hosting\Domains`

It seems from the name of the directory where actually `GiftShop` is located that it is a deployment location witch is served by a web server. If that is the case then i would strongly recommend you to separate your deployment from your development working copy